# Google app script for when a specific word/number is entered in a specific column range an alert will prompt the user

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the correct script or how to fix this script the way should be. The message alert should only appear whenever a **specific number is entered in a specific column range in a specific sheet (tab)**. But it does not follow, instead anything is entered in any cell, the message alert comes out. Thanks very much in advance.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange("E25:E26");
  if (cellValue == "70");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var message = ui.alert(
      'check manual',  
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Essential reading:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

  > **Return**
  > Range — the range at the location designated
- [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Array#flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

#### Issues:

- `if` syntax is `if(condition){statements}`. When you end `if(condition)` with `;` ,   following `statements` are  executed regardless of the condition.
- `getRange()` returns a `range` object and not a value. Objects cannot be compared with primitive types such as strings.

#### Solution:

- Valid if syntax.
- Get Value from range object to compare with strings

#### Snippet:

```
var cellValue = sheet.getRange("E25:E26").getValues().flat();
  if (cellValue.includes(70)){ var ui =....}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However I still couldn't run it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't use the 'getValue();' to actually read the value of your range. 
Besides that: if you want it to work on just one specific sheet, use 'getSheetByName'.

And of course you have to replace 'the_name_of_your_tab' with the actual name of your sheet.

```html
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('the_name_of_your_tab')
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange('E25:E26').getValue();
  if (cellValue == '70')
  {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var message = ui.alert(
      'check manual',  
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```